# Error: gtk_window_add_accel_group: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to set a key combination for `GtkMenuButton`. I made it through the Glade.

[image]

When loading the application I get the error: `Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_add_accel_group: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed`

[Glade File](http://paste.debian.net/plain/791195)
[Python code](http://paste.debian.net/plain/791197)

Comment: Please show both your code and your glade file.

Comment: You should try to produce a [mcve]. You have only added a link to your code, and not to SO. The code at your pastbin does not even run, so your problem is "it does not run". It does not reproduce the error message that you have stated.